# Como usar a auth con los Routes de Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

No sé si el Titulo lo escribí bien, pero así es como le entiendo.

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con laravel usando autenticación.

En `web.php` uso esta sentencia:

```
Route::resource('servicio', ServicioController::class)->middleware('auth');
```

Pero quiero que un usuario no logeado sí pueda entrar al método `show`.
Cuando lo intento no puedo ya que me envía al login.

¿Cómo puedo hacer una excepción a esta sentencia para poder ir al método `show` sin tener que pasar por el login?

*Nota*: la autentificacion la implementé asi: `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth`

Comment: O sea... ¿Quieres aplicar el middleware `auth` a todas las rutas del resource 'servicio', menos a la que corresponde a la función `show`?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ exacto, eso es lo que quiero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al declarar una ruta `resource`, puedes especificar un subconjunto de acciones que el controlador debe manejar en lugar del conjunto completo de acciones predeterminadas.

Con el método `except()` especificas que acciones no debe manejar esa ruta que requiere la autenticación:

```
Route::resource('servicio', ServicioController::class)
    ->except(['show'])
    ->middleware('auth');
```

Y luego creas otra ruta sin el middleware de autenticación, para las acciones que no lo requieran con el método `only()`:

```
Route::resource('servicio', ServicioController::class)
    ->only(['show']);
```

Referencia: [Resource Routes Parciales](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes)